# Printing sorted data from CSV

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have a CSV file with some rows of data which I if printed in Python, will look like this:

```
['1', 'George Washington', '1789-04-30', '1797-03-04', 'Independent ', 'Virginia']
['2', 'John Adams', '1797-03-04', '1801-03-04', 'Federalist ', 'Massachusetts']
['3', 'Thomas Jefferson', '1801-03-04', '1809-03-04', 'Democratic-Republican ', 'Virginia']
['4', 'James Madison', '1809-03-04', '1817-03-04', 'Democratic-Republican ', 'Virginia']
```

I need to print these 4 rows again but this time sorted by the second element. I tried this code:

```
import csv
csvdata=csv.reader(file('presidents.csv'))
for i in csvdata:
    i[1].sort()
    print i
```

But it does not work.

Comment: `.sort()` takes a `key` kwarg which you must use to tell it what element to sort by.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should use `open` and not `file`. To sort something, you need to give it a collection of things to sort; try this version instead:

```
with open('presidents.csv') as f:
   csvdata = csv.reader(f)
   rows = list(csvdata)

# sort the rows in-place

rows.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

print rows
```

You need to provide a custom `key` lookup, which is what the inline function lambda does. It basically tells the sort function to use the second element of each internal list to sort the outer list.

Keep in mind that `sort()` is an *in place sort* this means that it won't return the sorted list - in fact, it returns `None` which leads to surprises when you try this:

```
rows = rows.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Now `rows` will be `None`. If you want to have the unsorted list and the sorted list separate, use `sorted()`, but make sure you assign the result - like this:

```
sorted_rows = sorted(rows, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Comment: Why not just use `sorted` on `csvdata` ? (and `rows` could be put as `rows = list(csvdata)` anyhow)

Comment: @JonClements keeping in line with what the OP had tried. Thanks for the `list()` idea, I always forget that one.

Comment: the file should be opened with "rb", if you're using the csv.reader.

Comment: @monkut not necessarily - `csv.writer` recommends `rb`

Comment: wouldn't it be "wb" for `csv.writer`?

Answer (score 1):

Errrrm looks like you are trying to sort a string ^_^
From the docs here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

When you iterate through the csvreader you get rows one at a time...
So when you say i[1].sort()
i[1] = '1' (The first value in the first row of csv)

So try this:

```
import csv
fh = open('presidents.csv','rt')
csvdata=csv.reader(fh)
for row in csvdata:
    row.sort()
    print row
```

Edit -- 
Just Noticed the file thing :P